# Working with types up to a certain equivalence

Tags: idris, dependent-type

Suppose we'd like to represent (signed) integers as the Grothendieck group over naturals (or, in other words, as a pair `(m, n)`, where the integer that's understood is `m - n`):

```
data ZTy : Type where
  MkZ : (m, n : Nat) -> ZTy
```

Now the (structural) equality that the language gives us for free is no longer what we want: instead, we only care about a certain equivalence relation (namely, `(m1, n1) ~ (m2, n2)` iff `m1 + n2 = m2 + n1`). No biggie, let's write this down!

```
data Equiv : ZTy -> ZTy -> Type where
  MkEquiv : (prf : m1 + n2  = m2 + n1) -> Equiv (MkZ m1 n1) (MkZ m2 n2)
```

But working with this gets messy really quickly. Any argument of type `prop Const` (for `prop : ZTy -> Type`) is replaced with `` (k : ZTy) -> (k `EqZ` Const) -> prop k ``, to say the least (as a more applied example, I'm struggling with writing down the two-sided induction proof for this type, and I'm still not sure I got even the signature of that term right).

Moreover, a function like `` replaceZ : {P : ZTy -> Type} -> (k1 `Equiv` k2) -> P k1 -> P k2 `` (obviously) does not exist, but I cannot find a better candidate. As an interesting side note/observation, if we don't export the *definition* of `ZTy`, no client-code `P` can observe it, and this function would make sense for any `P` defined in any other module, but looks like we cannot internalize this within the language.

Another thing I have in mind is to limit the set of predicates to the ones that hold under equivalence relations. That is, replacing `P : ZTy -> Type` with something like `P : ZTy -> Type, pAdmissible : ZPred P` where `ZPred` carries along a proof of its invariance under the equivalence relation:

```
data ZPred : Type -> Type where
  MkZPred : {P : ZTy -> Type} ->
            (preservesEquiv : {k1, k2 : ZTy} -> (k1 `Equiv` k2) -> P k1 -> P k2) ->
            ZPred P
```

Anyway, what's the common approach to working with such types? Is there anything else that would work nicely?

I've also heard something about quotient types, but I don't know much.

Comment: We format code blocks with a 4-space indent on SO. The language is taken from the tags or manually given by `<!-- language: ___ -->` or `<!-- language-all: ___ -->` HTML comments; we just don't have a highlighter for Idris.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coq describes these situations with a rich language of "relation combinators", which is better version of your last idea. I'll translate it. You have

```
ZTy : Type -- as yours
```

And you proceed to define relations and functions on relations:

```
-- if r : Relation t and x, y : t, we say x and y are related by r iff r x y is inhabited
Relation : Type -> Type
Relation t = t -> t -> Type

-- if x, y : ZTy, we say x and y are (Equiv)alent iff Equiv x y is inhabited, etc.
Equiv : Relation ZTy  -- as yours
(=)   : Relation a    -- standard
Iso   : Relation Type -- standard

-- f and f' are related by a ==> r if arguments related by a end up related by r
(==>) : Relation a -> Relation b -> Relation (a -> b)
(==>) xr fxr = \f, f' => (x x' : a) -> xr x x' -> fxr (f x) (f' x')
infixr 10 ==>
```

The idea is that `Equiv`, `(=)`, and `Iso` are all equality relations. `Equiv` and `(=)` are two different notions of equality on `ZTy`, and `(=)` and `Iso` are two notions of equality on `Type`. `(==>)` combines relations into new relations.

If you have

```
P : ZTy -> Type
```

You would like to say that `Equiv`alent arguments map to `Iso`morphic types. That is, you need

```
replaceP : (x x' : ZTy) -> Equiv x x' -> Iso (P x) (P x')
```

How can the language of relations help? Well, `replaceP` is essentially saying that `P` is "equal" to itself, under the relation `Equiv ==> Iso` (N.B. `Equiv ==> Iso` is not an equivalence, but the only thing it's missing is reflexivity.) If a function is not "equal" to itself under `Equiv ==> Iso`, then that's a little bit like a "contradiction", and that function "doesn't exist" in your universe. Or, rather, if you want to write a function

```
f : (ZTy -> Type) -> ?whatever
```

You can restrict yourself to the correct kind of functions by requiring a proof argument like so

```
Proper : Relation a -> a -> Type
Proper r x = r x x

f : (P : ZTy -> Type) -> Proper (Equiv ==> Iso) P -> ?whatever
```

Usually, though, you leave off the proof unless absolutely needed. In fact, the standard library already contains a lot of functions on `ZTy`, like

```
concatMap : Monoid m => (ZTy -> m) -> List ZTy -> m
```

Instead of writing a `concatMap` taking a proof argument, you really only have to write a proof about `concatMap`:

```
concatMapProper : Proper ((Equiv ==> (=)) ==> Pairwise Equiv ==> (=))
-- you'd really abstract over Equiv and (=), but then you need classes for Relations
Pairwise : Relation a -> Relation [a] -- as you may guess
```

I'm not sure what induction principle you want to write, so I'll just leave that alone. However, your concern that

```
proof : Property Constant
```

always needs to be replaced with

```
proof : (k : ZTy) -> Equiv k Constant -> Property k
```

is only partially well-founded. If you already have

```
PropertyProper : Proper (Equiv ==> Iso) Property
```

which you very likely should, then you can write `proper : Property Constant`, and just shove it through `PropertyProper` to generalize it when needed. (Or, write `proper` with the general signature by using the simple definition with `PropertyProper` on top). You can't get out of writing a proof *somewhere* though, because it simply isn't that trivial.

It's also worth noting that `(==>)` has uses other than as the argument to `Proper`. It serves as a general purpose extensional equality:

```
abs1 : ZTy -> Nat
abs1 (MkZ l r) = go l r
  where go (S n) (S m) = go n m
        go Z     m     = m
        go n     Z     = n
abs2 : ZTy -> Nat
abs2 (MkZ l r) = max l r - min l r

absEq : (Equiv ==> (=)) abs1 abs2
--    : (x x' : ZTy) -> Equiv x x' -> abs1 x = abs2 x'
```

Comment: I'll have to think through this and spend some time internalizing these ideas, but this is awesome, thanks! And I probably should finally learn Coq.